# Cast with long if else statements or using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have a performance question, using C# over .Net4.

I get a distributed object which I need to cast to one of many types. My question is: which way is better?

1. Cast it with a long if else (!= null) statements.
2. Get the type of the object with reflection and use one successful cast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a better answer here than "profile it", especially not without knowing how many types you have.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use a virtual method and polymorphism - then you don't need to do anything - you'd just call:

```
obj.SomeVirtualMethod(args);
```

and let the `virtual`/`override` etc figure out what to do.

If the object is under your control,  and you mean subtypes of your specific base-type, then I would consider adding a discriminator, i.e. an enum property that reveals the nature of the underlying type, i.e.

```
Foo foo = ...
switch(foo.Actual)
{
    case FooType.Alpha: DoSomethingWith((Alpha) foo); break;
    case FooType.Beta: DoSomethingElseWith((Beta) foo); break;
    ...
}
```

For a framework/BCL example of this, look at Expression.NodeType.

For primitives (`long` etc), look at `Type.GetTypeCode()` which again allows for a switch usage. If it isn't primitive, you can do something similar by pre-registering your *expected* types in a dictionary somewhere, allowing you to (again) flip into a `switch`.